# Python scraping from a complex HTML file

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have a huge html file. I want to scrape certain info. from it. Basically there are some 2000 variables and each has some values. I need these values and variable names in this format -
varname1,val1,val2,...
varname2,val1,val2...
..
..

The values are in this format -

---

```
<h2><span lang=EN-US>Element Values</span></h2>

<p class=MsoListParagraph><span lang=EN-US style='mso-no-proof:yes'>01 = 01<o:p></o:p></span></p>

<p class=MsoListParagraph><span lang=EN-US style='mso-no-proof:yes'>02<o:p></o:p></span></p>
.
.
.

<p class=MsoListParagraph style='line-height:normal'><span lang=EN-US
style='mso-no-proof:yes'>20[true]</span></p>

<p class=MsoListParagraph style='line-height:normal'><span lang=EN-US
 style='font-size:6.0pt;mso-bidi-font-size:12.0pt'><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></p>

<h2><span lang=EN-US>Element Notes</span></h2>
```

---

I need the values 01=01,02,...,20[true]

The variable names are always in this format -

```
<span style='mso-no-proof:yes'>2716</span>
```

i.e 4 digits inside that span tag.

so 1 output could be 2716,01=01,02,...,20[true]

Comment: You've tagged your question with [beautifulsoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) (doco). Have you tried using it? Please post your code.

Comment: I have only 1 day of experience with python. I was able to find the variable names with - varname = soup.find_all('span', text = re.compile('\S(4)')), where soup has the file read in it

Comment: Would it be at all possible for you to put a part of the html file on pastebin so we can get a better understanding of the structure of the file? For example, I don't see the "variable" declaration in the snippet you posted.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/RcTCGUCP; there is no variable declaration as such, tags like this one - <span style='mso-no-proof:yes'>2716</span> gives the variable name. 2716 in this case @CanIbanoglu

Comment: **Edit the question** to include the relevant information. @CanIbanoglu you should not encourage OPs to post material off-site. However this question is too broad; maybe spend more than one day getting to grips with the tool you're trying to use.

Comment: All relevant and sufficient information is already supplied in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will match the required tags (`span` tags with attribute `style` set to `mso-no-proof:yes`), it's then a matter of extracting the text.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """<h2><span lang=EN-US>Element Values</span></h2>
<p class=MsoListParagraph><span lang=EN-US style='mso-no-proof:yes'>01 = 01<o:p></o:p></span></p>
<p class=MsoListParagraph><span lang=EN-US style='mso-no-proof:yes'>02<o:p></o:p></span></p>
<p class=MsoListParagraph style='line-height:normal'><span lang=EN-US
style='mso-no-proof:yes'>20[true]</span></p>
<p class=MsoListParagraph style='line-height:normal'><span lang=EN-US
 style='font-size:6.0pt;mso-bidi-font-size:12.0pt'><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></p>
<h2><span lang=EN-US>Element Notes</span></h2>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
elements = soup.find_all(name='span', attrs={'style' : 'mso-no-proof:yes'})
print ','.join(e.text for e in elements)
```

Outputs:

```
01 = 01,02,20[true]
```

Comment: thanks, i can do the rest. Should i delete the question?

Comment: No, don't delete the question! Leave it there to help others. Mark it as accepted if you are happy that it solves the problem.